# How to move pictures from app/media to app/webroot/img in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP 1.2 and when I upload new pictures they are stored in a folder such as "app\media\Deal\585", where "585" is the number of the deal and "Deal" is the name of my controller, but in general all of the pictures I upload end up being stored in this folder: "app\media\". However, in order to access the uploaded pictures from a view, I would need to move the images to this location: "app\webroot\img". In the view file, this is how I am trying to access the pictures:

```
$imageUrl = $html->getImageUrl('Deal', $deal['Picture'][0], array('dimension' => 'wide_big_thumb', 'alt' => sprintf(__l('[Image: %s]'), $html->cText($deal['Deal']['name'], false)), 'title' => $html->cText($deal['Deal']['name'], false)));
echo $html->image($imageUrl, array('width' => '100%', 'alt' => sprintf(__l('[Image: %s]'), $html->cText($deal['Deal']['name'], false)), 'title' => $html->cText($deal['Deal']['name'], false)));
```

$html->image() is generating the corresponding  tag, but it is trying to find the image at "app\webroot\img". Do you know about ways or maybe convensions for CakePHP to move images in my case from "app\media\" (where images are uploaded) to "app\webroot\img" (the directory that is accessible directly from a web browser)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently this was not code from a popular plug-in nor standard or conventional CakePHP code to generate images. It seemed to me more like customized additions, and if that is the case nobody was supposed to know the answer. I made it work and everything is fine now.